# Can the compiler used (gcc / llvm) to compile Python and extensions affect the performance?

Tags: python, gcc, llvm, compiler-optimization

BTW, for those python modules (especially C extension), some use `openmp`, if I use `gcc` with `openmp` to compile, I think it will be much faster? Am I right?
For most cases, I think `gcc` does better on code optimization. 
However, I think use `brew` in OSX, it will directly give me a `llvm` compiled binaries. Do I need to recompile my python and those python modules in `gcc` to improve performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends a lot on the python modules you are compiling. If these python modules make use of OpenMP, then enabling OpenMP will make them faster, yes. By the way, also LLVM/clang [supports OpenMP by now](http://blog.llvm.org/2015/05/openmp-support_22.html), but I don't know if it is already enabled in brew.

GCC and LLVM performance are similar and, [depending on the compiled code](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=clang-gcc-broadwell&num=4), either of them can be faster.

If you're really concerned about the speed of the python code, you could try a faster python interpreter instead, like [pypy](http://speed.pypy.org/).